# How to dynamically assig keys to buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyevent

I have a section in my GUI that is generated dynamically according to a list of objects.
So, for each object in that list I want to create a JButton and associate a keyboard shortcut.

For example:

```
for (String tag : testTags) {
    new JButton(tag).setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
}
```

How do I make the code "setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F1)" dynamic in an elegant way? Is there some way to get a range of keys automatically and then use it in this iteration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) is well suited for this. See [*How to Use Actions*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more.

Comment: In the long run, this is the best way to go.

Comment: Oh, nice. I actually didn't know about actions. This seems to solve my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
AbstractButton.setMnemonic(int)
```

Just iterate through the range of accepted ints.

Comment: Something like:
`int key = 112;
new JButton(tag).setMnemonic(key++)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Either create an array containing your Keys with

```
int[] keys = {KeyEvent.VK_F1,KeyEvent.VK_F2,[...]};
```

or iterate over the range of the F1-F12 keys (112 - 123)

```
int key = KeyEvent.VK_F1;
for (String s : strings) {
    new JButton(s).setMnemonic(key++);
}
```

You do have to check if *key* is still in range (123 being F12), though.